# Calculate time difference between events

Tags: t-sql

I have the following data:

```
Truck   Trigger     Geolocation Position Date-
ID      Event       Event       Time UTC
TR0025  ENTERING    20KMH ZONE  26/10/2023 18:04
TR0025  EXITING     20KMH ZONE  26/10/2023 18:06
TR0025  ENTERING    ROM ZONE    26/10/2023 18:08
TR0025  EXITING     ROM ZONE    26/10/2023 18:12
TR0025  ENTERING    20KMH ZONE  26/10/2023 19:02
TR0025  EXITING     20KMH ZONE  26/10/2023 19:04
TR0025  ENTERING    ROM ZONE    26/10/2023 19:06
TR0025  EXITING     ROM ZONE    26/10/2023 19:10
+TR0026 EXITING     MAINTENANCE 26/10/2023 20:28
+TR0026 EXITING     PIT 2       27/10/2023 14:49
+TR0026 ENTERING    ROM ZONE    27/10/2023 14:55
+TR0026 EXITING     PIT 2       27/10/2023 15:17
TR0026  ENTERING    ROM ZONE    27/10/2023 15:25
TR0026  EXITING     ROM ZONE    27/10/2023 15:29
```

I'd like to be able to calculate the time difference between consecutive Entries and Exits.
However, the issue is at times there may not be a corresponding Entry or Exit (marked with + above).

I would like to end up with something like below for each Truck by date

```
[Date]      [Truck ID]  [Geolocation Event] [Cumulative Time]
26/10/2023  TR0025      20KMH ZONE          230 min (Just the int)
```

I think I will need to ensure the pattern is correct first removing the Zones that don't match the ENTERING-EXITING pattern. I could then self-join on an ID field. I'm not sure of an approach on how to enforce the pattern as a first step.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are geolocations nested, e.g. if Enter A, Enter B, Exit B, Exit A possible for a distinct truck?

Comment: How do you get `230 min` for `20KMH ZONE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Truck log data as provided in the question
WITH t AS (
    SELECT v.[Truck], v.[Trigger], v.[Geolocation], CONVERT(datetime2, v.[Position], 103) [Position]
    FROM (VALUES
        ('TR0025', 'ENTERING', '20KMH ZONE', '26/10/2023 18:04'),
        ('TR0025', 'EXITING', '20KMH ZONE', '26/10/2023 18:06'),
        ('TR0025', 'ENTERING', 'ROM ZONE', '26/10/2023 18:08'),
        ('TR0025', 'EXITING', 'ROM ZONE', '26/10/2023 18:12'),
        ('TR0025', 'ENTERING', '20KMH ZONE', '26/10/2023 19:02'),
        ('TR0025', 'EXITING', '20KMH ZONE', '26/10/2023 19:04'),
        ('TR0025', 'ENTERING', 'ROM ZONE', '26/10/2023 19:06'),
        ('TR0025', 'EXITING', 'ROM ZONE', '26/10/2023 19:10'),
        ('TR0026', 'EXITING', 'MAINTENANCE', '26/10/2023 20:28'),
        ('TR0026', 'EXITING', 'PIT 2', '27/10/2023 14:49'),
        ('TR0026', 'ENTERING', 'ROM ZONE', '27/10/2023 14:55'),
        ('TR0026', 'EXITING', 'PIT 2', '27/10/2023 15:17'),
        ('TR0026', 'ENTERING', 'ROM ZONE', '27/10/2023 15:25'),
        ('TR0026', 'EXITING', 'ROM ZONE', '27/10/2023 15:29')
    ) v([Truck], [Trigger], [Geolocation], [Position])
), 
-- Entering events
Entering AS (
    SELECT t.Truck, t.Geolocation, t.Position
    FROM t
    WHERE t.[Trigger]='ENTERING'
), 
-- Exiting events
Exiting AS (
    SELECT t.Truck, t.Geolocation, t.Position
    FROM t
    WHERE t.[Trigger]='EXITING'
), 
-- Correlated events
Events AS (
    SELECT ISNULL(Entering.Truck, Exiting.Truck) Truck, ISNULL(Entering.Geolocation, Exiting.Geolocation) Geolocation, Entering.Position EnterPosition, Exiting.Position ExitPosition, DATEDIFF(Minute, Entering.Position, Exiting.Position) Time
    FROM Entering
    FULL JOIN Exiting ON Entering.Truck=Exiting.Truck 
        AND Entering.Geolocation=Exiting.Geolocation 
        AND Entering.Position<=Exiting.Position 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM t 
            WHERE t.Truck=Entering.Truck 
            AND t.Position>Entering.Position 
            AND t.Position<Exiting.Position)
)
SELECT *
    FROM Events
```

The `NOT EXISTS (...)` makes sure that there exists no log entry by the same truck in the timeframe between a matched ENTERING and EXITING. If geolocation zones can be nested, you'd need to extend this part of the condition.

Now if you want to get the cumulative time, just do a group by on the correlated events:

```
WITH ...
SELECT Truck, Geolocation, SUM(Time) [Cumulative Time]
    FROM Events
    WHERE Time IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Truck, Geolocation
```

Note: I used a `FULL JOIN` so that you can also see the uncorrelated events, if you don't want them you can just use a normal inner join.

Comment: <pre-tea> When I first read "normal inner join" I thought it sounds like a 90° `cross join`. </pre-tea>

Comment: Thanks Lucero - This did the trick.

Comment: @Smithy You're welcome. An upvote would have been nice though.

Comment: @Lucero - Yes I tried to Upvote, but it tells me I don't have 15 reputation. Sorry

Comment: @Smithy now you do 

Comment: @Lucero - So I do